# Excel Validation to Prevent Entry of Two Specific Characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I'd like to place some validation against a cell in Excel that allows all characters except a "-" (hyphen) and any white space. I've attempted the following but this doesn't seem to work.

```
=ISERROR((OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",C14)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ",C14)))))
```

If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT:  USE =LEN(B3)=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B3,"-","")," ","")) or =AND(ISERROR(FIND(" ",B3)),ISERROR(FIND("-",B3)))

@[chris neilsen](https://superuser.com/users/67240/chris-neilsen)-Thank you

I think the right direction is around [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal07.html).
If the formatting is a bit 'off' Just follow the link above.

To expand the usefulness of my answer, I added some information for people who may have similar questions.

> ## Excel Data Validation Examples Custom Criteria
>
> ### Prevent Duplicates With Data Validation
>
> You can use Excel Data Validation to prevent duplicate entries in a range on
>   the worksheet. In this example, Employee Numbers will be entered in cells
>   B3:B10, and you can prevent the same number from being entered twice..
>
> 1. Select cells B3:B10
> 2. Choose Data|Data Validation
> 3. Choose Allow: Custom
> 4. For the formula in this example, we use the COUNTIF function to count
>      the occurrences of the value in cell B3, in the range $B$3:$B$10. The
>      formula's result must be 1 or 0:

**=COUNTIF($B$3:$B$10,B3) <= 1**

**Limit the Total**

> Prevent the entry of a value that will cause a range to exceed a set total.
>   In this example, the total budget cannot exceed $3500. The budget amounts are
>   in cells C3:C7, and the formula checks the total in those cells
>
> 1. Select cells C3:C7
> 2. Choose Data|Data Validation
> 3. Choose Allow: Custom
> 4. For the formula, use SUM to total the values in the range $C$3:$C$7.
>      The result must be less than or equal to $3500:

**=SUM($C$3:$C$7) <= 3500**

> [image: data validation 02]
>
> ### **No Leading or Trailing Spaces**
>
> You can prevent users from adding spaces before or after the text in the
>   entry. The TRIM function removes spaces before and after the text, and any
>   extra spaces within the text.
>
> The formula in this example checks that the entry in cell B2 is equal to the
>   trimmed entry in that cell.
>
> 1. Select cell B2
> 2. Choose Data|Data Validation
> 3. Choose Allow: Custom
> 4. For the formula, enter:

**=B2 = TRIM(B2)**

> [image: data validation 03]
>
> ### **No Spaces in Text**
>
> *Thanks to [Jerry Latham](http://www.jlathamsite.com/LearningPage.htm) for
>   this example.*
>
> You can prevent users from adding ANY spaces in a text string. The
>   SUBSTITUTE function replaces each space character  " "  with an empty string
>    ""
>
> The formula in this example checks that the entry in cell B3 is equal to the
>   entry without spaces.
>
> 1. Select cell B3
> 2. On the Ribbon, click the Data tab, then click Data Validation
> 3. Choose Allow: Custom
> 4. For the formula, enter:

**=B3=SUBSTITUTE(B3," ","")**
>

> [image: data validation no spaces]
>
> ### **No Spaces in Cell**
>
> You can prevent users from adding ANY spaces in the cell -- whether the
>   entry is text, numbers, or a combination of both. Here are two formulas that
>   check for spaces.
>
> #### Example 1
>
> *Thanks to [Jerry Latham](http://www.jlathamsite.com/LearningPage.htm) for
>   this example.*
>
> The LEN function counts the number of characters entered in cell B3, and
>   compares that to the number of characters after SUBSTITUTE removes the space
>   characters.
>
> 1. Select cell B3
> 2. On the Ribbon, click the Data tab, then click Data Validation
> 3. Choose Allow: Custom
> 4. For the formula, enter:

**=LEN(B3)=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3," ",""))**

> [image: data validation no spaces]
>
> #### Example 2
>
> The FIND function looks for the space character  " "  and the ISERROR
>   function result is TRUE, if the space character is not found.
>
> The formula in this example checks that the entry in cell B3 is equal to the
>   entry without spaces.
>
> 1. Select cell B3
> 2. On the Ribbon, click the Data tab, then click Data Validation
> 3. Choose Allow: Custom
> 4. For the formula, enter:

**=ISERROR(FIND(" ",B3))**

> [image: data validation no spaces]

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to prevent the entry of one specific character but I'm struggling to prevent entry of two seperate characters, in this case a hyphen & a space..

Comment: Oh... I'll look again for what you can do...

Comment: The examples are easily extendable to multiple characters - `=LEN(B3)=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B3,"-","")," ",""))` or `=AND(ISERROR(FIND(" ",B3)),ISERROR(FIND("-",B3)))`

Comment: @chrisneilsen - many thanks for this, works a treat, paticularly like the first option, I hadn't though of that. Thanks again. Joe

Comment: how should I now flag this question as answered? Does it go against the original answer or @chrisneilsen ? Thanks

Comment: @aphrek I coppied the answer chris neilsen wrote, and cited him.  Therefore, my answer is now complete (might even be over-complete).