# Excel Validation: How to prevent duplicate entries globally within workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to prevent duplicate code assignments within the same workbook but across several worksheets.  The entries will be manually assigned and entered, and ideally I'd like to have, e.g., data validation come up with an error message and stop on entry attempt.  I'm looking for a solution that **does not involve VB** or `.xlsm`.

I've referenced several online sources — as well as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/356326/excel-validation-to-prevent-entry-of-two-specific-characters/356346#356346) SU post — but everything I've found seems to be intended for use within the confines of a single worksheet reference.

I've tried experimenting on my own, but wasn't able to get validation to work when attempting to reference multiple ranges located on multiple sheets.  I then thought to use a `Data` sheet that aggregates all the entries across the worksheet input ranges into one table, and applied Data Validation on that range instead.  Unfortunately, it seems that Data Validation will not trip on initial input; only if you refresh the cell — e.g., <kbd>F2</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> — does the error message come up.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are U looking for method, should never allow duplicates across sheets or in any specific column/columns in Workbook ?

Comment: Hi @RajeshS I could have sworn I replied to you already, but I guess I never hit <kbd>Add Comment</kbd>.  To clarify, I was looking for a method to apply this to a user-defined range across multiple tabs (within one workbook); so to answer your question, it would be the latter if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: Hi @Arctiic , I can suggest U VBA macro  will help U do avoid duplicates across sheets,, in particular column,, if yes please confirm through comments also,, [edit] your post and add TAG `VBA` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the technique laid out in the Contextures article https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal03.html

Build a list of values in a helper sheet in column A

For the formula in column B, where the used values are counted, you could use a simple OR statement that looks at all the cells in all the sheets where the same DV list is used, like

```
=OR(Sheet2!$D$3=A2,Sheet2!$H$5=A2,Sheet3!$B$6=A2,Sheet3!$C$13=A2)+0
```

Any formula that will give you a reliable 1 or 0 for each value will do.

If you have Office 365, you can replace the Index function (suggested in the article) for column C with a much simpler Filter() function.

```
=FILTER(A2:A8,B2:B8=0)
```

Then build a named range with the formula

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$1,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$C:$C),1)
```

and assign that range name to the DV cells as the list source.

In the screenshot one cell in Sheet 3 contains the value "AA", a cell in Sheet 2 contains the value "FF". Therefore, these two values are not available for selection in the DV dropdown anymore.

[image]